# Is it ok to equalize mic signal?

Tags: production

I have different microphones (dynamic and condenser ). And what i want you to ask is is it ok to equalize singnal from they. For example from condeser sometimes it too bright or from cheap dynamic mics signal is always dull but what i think is if i equalize audio from dynamic mic is will ruin it. It will be no more the same. For example i want to boost +12dB high frequencies on dynamic mic because it's so dull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **always** alright to eq the signal from a mic - whatever sort of mic that is. And even regarding the sort of voice the singer using that mic has, or the sound he wants.

That's why, on a half-decent mixer, there's a minimum of two tone controls - treble and bass - on better ones, there's often 3 or 4. That's what they're there for! Mics are different, voices are different, and heck, rooms are different. All calling for a little fettling of those tone controls. In the same breath, the *gain*, found on most mixers, is there to level up the volume of each mic. And it's not, as I was once told, to show that the mic needing the least gain was the best mic!

I love it when the sound guy 'checks' the mics. He hasn't the same voice as me; he doesn't know what eq (or relative volume) **I** want, but he's 'checked' it. Maybe he's just checking the mic actually works...

Comment: Thanks, but there may be better answers coming from folk who haven't woken to read this yet. Give them a chance too !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's OK to equalise.

But, if you want it to sound good, keep two things in mind.

It's generally better to cut than to boost. For a brighter sound, try cutting mid and bass rather than boosting top.

Don't overdo it.  12dB is a LOT of boost!   And you can't boost what isn't there!  Maybe that 'cheap dynamic' is a bit TOO cheap?